# NotSerializableException for Activity when serializing something completely different

Tags: java, android, android-activity, serialization

I have an Android Activity (CashFlowActivity) which lets the user create some data. When they leave the Activity, I check to see if the data has been changed and save it to my DB if so.

When saving to the DB, I serialize my data structure and store it as a byte[] in a blob.

My data structure is a CashflowSeries which extends ArrayList. Both CashflowSeries and CashFlow are Serializable. The weird part is that the NotSerializeableException I'm getting is complaining about the CashFlowActivity.

And it happens on `oos.defaultWriteObject();` in CashFlow.writeObject(), which is also very confusing.

Here is the stacktrace for the exception:

```
06-30 19:48:42.764  13555-13555/com.inadaydevelopment.cashcalculator E/serializeObject﹕ error
    java.io.NotSerializableException: com.inadaydevelopment.cashcalculator.CashFlowActivity
            at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNewObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1364)
            at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal(ObjectOutputStream.java:1671)
            at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1517)
            at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1481)
            at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeFieldValues(ObjectOutputStream.java:979)
            at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:368)
            at com.inadaydevelopment.cashcalculator.CashFlow.writeObject(CashFlow.java:37)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeHierarchy(ObjectOutputStream.java:1053)
            at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNewObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1404)
            at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal(ObjectOutputStream.java:1671)
            at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1517)
            at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1481)
            at java.util.ArrayList.writeObject(ArrayList.java:644)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeHierarchy(ObjectOutputStream.java:1053)
            at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNewObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1404)
            at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal(ObjectOutputStream.java:1671)
            at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1517)
            at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1481)
            at com.inadaydevelopment.cashcalculator.DBAdapter.serializeObject(DBAdapter.java:1428)
            at com.inadaydevelopment.cashcalculator.DBAdapter.saveCashFlowSeries(DBAdapter.java:505)
            at com.inadaydevelopment.cashcalculator.CashFlowActivity.saveSeries(CashFlowActivity.java:175)
```

Here is the CashFlowSeries which is the top level object I'm trying to serialize:

```
public class CashFlowSeries extends ArrayList<CashFlow> implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2665343990201574019L;

    private double numPeriodsPerYear;

    private Formatter formatter;
    private CashFlowSeriesDelegate delegate;


    private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream oos) throws IOException{
        oos.defaultWriteObject();

        oos.writeDouble(this.numPeriodsPerYear);
        oos.writeInt(this.size());

        for(CashFlow cashFlow : this) {
            oos.writeObject(cashFlow);
        }

    }
    //... more stuff
}
```

Here is the CashFlow class which is what is contained in the CashFlowSeries list, and is where the exception is being thrown:

```
public class CashFlow implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7315728302372918920L;

    private static final String TAG = "CashFlow";

    private CashFlowSeries series;

    private String amountString;
    private String numRepetitionsString;

    private boolean isValidAmount;
    private boolean isValidNumRepetitions;

    private Formatter formatter;
    private CashFlowSeriesDelegate cashFlowSeriesDelegate;

    public CashFlow() {
        this.formatter = Formatter.getInstance();
        this.amountString = "";
        this.numRepetitionsString = "";
    }



    private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream oos) throws IOException {
        oos.defaultWriteObject(); // EXCEPTION THROWN HERE

        oos.writeObject(this.amountString);
        oos.writeObject(this.numRepetitionsString);

        oos.writeBoolean(this.isValidAmount);
        oos.writeBoolean(this.isValidNumRepetitions);
    }

    // ... more stuff
}
```

p

```
ublic static byte[] serializeObject(Object o) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    try {
        ObjectOutput out = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);
        out.writeObject(o);
        out.close();

        // Get the bytes of the serialized object
        byte[] buf = bos.toByteArray();

        return buf;
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        Log.e("serializeObject", "error", ioe);

        return null;
    }
}
```

I have no idea why it's trying to serialize the Activity.. or is that just a red herring?

Comment: Is there an equivalent of the JVM flag `-Dsun.io.serialization.extendedDebugInfo=true` in Android? That might give a hint as to the chain of things being serialized.

Comment: Please post the code of `DBAdapter.serializeObject`

Comment: What is `CashFlowSeriesDelegate`? If you are writing your own data via `write...()`, why are you calling `defaultWriteObject()`? For example, if `CashFlowSeriesDelegate` is an interface, and `CashFlowActivity` implements that interface, your `defaultWriteObject()` call will try writing out your `CashFlowActivity` (along with the rest of your data members) and you would get the above stack trace.

Comment: @CommonsWare As far as I read, the writeObject() method is ALWAYS supposed to start with that defaultWriteObject() call. For example: http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=45 I'm guessing that I read incorrectly and it should be one or the other?

Comment: "I'm guessing that I read incorrectly and it should be one or the other?" -- I think it's redundant, as AFAIK `defaultWriteObject()` should be writing all that stuff for you. To avoid the problems that `defaultWriteObject()` is causing, perhaps the `CashFlowSeriesDelegate` data member should be marked `transient`.

Comment: Your actual problem is probably caused by serializing an inner class of an `Activity`. You don't need the entire `writeObject()` method, but if you keep it you shouldn't repeat what `defaultWriteObject()` is already doing. You also don't need to serialize the `Formatter`.

Comment: @EJP I'm not serializing an inner class of an Activity.